# Does Wata no Kunihoshi manga have a continuation after chapter 6, or an anime adaptation?

Tags: wata-no-kunihoshi

The manga is called Wata no Kunihoshi (in English, "The Star of Cottonland") and it is a shōjo manga by Yumiko Ōshima.

It's about a kitten girl named Chibi NeKo. I've read all the way to chapter six, and can't seem to find a chapter seven.

Do you have any information at all, regarding the continuation of the series or any adaptations it may have had in animation?

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Star_of_Cottonland), the manga ran for seven volumes and there was an anime film of it. Unfortunately, since this is an older series, the manga was probably never officially released in English. [Here's](https://slightlybiasedmanga.com/2011/08/12/english-please-star-of-cottonlan/) a blog from 2011 asking for an English release, which implies there hadn't been one up to that point. According to [this column on Anime News Network](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/buried-treasure/2007-06-07), the anime was never released in English.

Comment: So there are more MaNgA chapters to Wata No Kunihoshi past the chp 6 that the site MangaHere has currently available???

Comment: Yes, there are. Usually a volume contains 6-10 chapters, so seven volumes would mean there are 42-70 chapters. Unfortunately, I couldn't find any evidence the chapters had been translated. My guess is a scanlation group did the first volume and then gave up on it, which seems to happen with a lot of older manga.

Comment: I'm so happy to know that there are still chapters out there, would there be any way for me to get the series to get picked up by someone so that all 7 volumes can be completely translated???

Comment: Or if anything a place where I can read the RAWS???

Comment: You could try getting a Kickstarter going to fund an English release, like was done for [Skip Beat](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/85938147/skip-beat-official-north-american-release). I don't know where you might go to find raws.

Comment: A kick starter, and how would it work?

Comment: Where can I find a group to pick it up?

Comment: I don't know. It's worth asking a separate question to see if anyone knows how these Kickstarters get going. You might also have to do some research on your own to find out.

Comment: Man, it's difficult to fully enjoy a series when it hasn't even been completely translated, because it leaves so many unanswered questions and concerns...(  T ^ T)/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wata no Kunihoshi has a total of 24 chapters, divided in 7 volumes, which were published between 1978 and 1984. There was also a movie, released in 1984.

Fortunately, someone might have heard your request, and chapter 7 got a fan translation just a few days ago (August 10). I'm sure you can find it. Hopefully the rest gets translated too, at some point.